# how to print selected value from dropdown API

Tags: angular, rest

I have an API Array that looks like below -

```
    [
     "abcdefg",
     "xyshgje",
     "fjgyros"
    ]
```

I am trying to capture the value of selected object from the array in angualr 2 -

```
<select (change)="onChangeofOptions($event.target.value)" name="someName" class="form-control">
                <option value="A">All</option><br>
                <option *ngFor="let tam of tamValues" value="tam">{{tam}}</option>
              </select>
```

the above code prints(in console) "A" as expected when selected ALL from the drop down. And it prints "tam" when I select one of the values from the array list. The API call for the array looks like this -

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get("http://example.url.com")
      .map((res: Response) => (
        res.json()
      ))
      .subscribe(result=> {
        this.tamValues= result;
      })
  }
```

Am i doing something wrong here? I want to print the selected value from the array that is being populated in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[value]="tam"`

```
<select (change)="onChangeofOptions($event.target.value)" name="someName" class="form-control">
                <option value="A">All</option><br>
                <option *ngFor="let tam of tamValues" [value]="tam">{{tam}}</option>
              </select>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qeswdh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way is to Use **`ngModel`** with **`ngModelChange`** event as follows

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedtam" (ngModelChange)="onChangeofOptions($event)">
   <option value="A">All</option><br>
      <option *ngFor="let tam of tamValues" value={{tam}}>{{tam}}</option>
</select>
```

[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)